# Is it safe to save changes to a running PHP script?

Tags: php

I've got a very long running PHP CLI script that will take hours to process. Is it safe to edit that script while it's running to start working on the next sprint, or do I need to leave the working directory alone and work on a copy instead?

The only reason I ask the question is because I feel like it might already be loaded into memory, so any edits I make to the script on disk won't affect the currently running process. Basically I'm worried that if I start working on the script it will break the process that's already running.

Thanks

Comment: if its running, then you wont be editing the version the OS is using. but if you want to be safe just make a copy.

Comment: php code is just plain text. it's not an executable. once the text is loaded into the php parser for execution, the script file is closed and basically ignored. you can replace that now-unused file anytime without affecting what's (still) executing in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is: it depends on how the file is loaded.

The `include` and `require` statements are processed during runtime. If an `include` or `require` statement is used in a loop, the included file is read and parsed every time the `include` or `require` statement is executed.

Let's suppose the file `main.php` contains something like this:

```
<?php

include 'a.php';
include_once 'b.php';

while (true) {
    include 'c.php';
    include_once 'd.php';
}
```

You type `php main.php` in a console and it keep running for hours.

Let's assume the `while ()` loop was already executed at least once.
It's safe to modify `main.php`, `a.php`, `b.php` and `d.php`. All these were loaded by the interpreter in memory and parsed. Their source files are not read again.

**But `c.php` is read and parsed again and again on every iteration.**

If you modify it, your changes will be loaded on the next loop and they can break the execution (because most of the time you are working on the code it doesn't compile.)

The same situation happens when `c.php` is included in a function that is called multiple times or when it is included in another file that is included again and again, etc.

The entire discussion above applies if `include` is replaced by `require` and `include_once` by `require_once` (apart from the way they handle a missing file, `include` and `require` work the same way).

Comment: I'm curious how this works with autoloaded classes. Are all the classes loaded at startup, or only called when they're actually used? How would I be able to tell if a class had been loaded? Maybe just safest to work on a copy of the repository? Sorry for all the followup questions.

Comment: When the script starts no user-defined class is loaded by default. The script starts running and the autoloader is invoked when the code needs to use a class that was not already loaded. The `use` statements just define aliases, they do not trigger the loading of the class (the aliased class might not even exist). The autoloader **does not** load a file twice; it doesn't have any reason to do it.

Comment: OK thanks, so if I understand you correctly, in the context of this problem, it works the same as an include_once?

Comment: More or less. The interpreter invokes the functions registered using [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) (aka the "auto-loader(s)") once for each new class it encounters during the runtime. However, an auto-loader (which is user code btw) may decide to [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the same file every time it is invoked. Back to the issue that generated your question, the sanest thing to do is to use different environments for development and production.

Answer (score 0):

While the script is running you can modify the file but it will not have any effect. The script is loaded once at execution-time. If you want to execute changed PHP file you will need to reload/run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Once the script is loaded, then yes, it's safe to edit.

But if you're including other files, then those are loaded at runtime and will affect your overall program execution.

#### `main.php`

```
$i = 10;

while(--$i){
    echo $i.PHP_EOL;
    sleep(1);
    include 'inc.php';
}
```

#### `inc.php`

```
echo "included\n";
```

Run the script, and then editing `inc.php`

```
echo "asdf\n";
```

Will lead to output like this:

> ```
> 9
> included
> 8
> included
> 7
> included
> 6
> asdf
> 5
> asdf
> 4
> asdf
> 3
> asdf
> 2
> asdf
> 1
> asdf
> ```